# How to get all interfaces of a class in roslyn analyzer

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to analyze whether a class implements a specific interface, concrete I am looking if the class implements `IEquatable<T>` and if so I want to raise a report.

eg:

```
   class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
   {
      ...
   }
```

Until now I was not able to find a way to get all interfaces of the current class.

- Which `AnalysisContext.RegisterX` do I need to call?
- How do I get the interfaces from the analyzer?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();

    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(CheckClassForInterfaces, SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration);
}

private static void CheckClassForInterfaces(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var classDeclarationSyntax = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
    var declaredSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclarationSyntax);
    var equatableInterfaceType = context.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.IEquatable`1");

    foreach (var interfaceTypeSymbol in namedTypeSymbol.Interfaces)
    {
        if (interfaceTypeSymbol.Name == equatableInterfaceType?.Name)
        {
            // Report your diagnostic here
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to get the generic type, it gets a little more complicated, but you can get the type like this and then construct it:

```
var declaredSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclarationSyntax);
var typeDefinition = declaredSymbol.TypeParameters[0].OriginalDefinition;
var equatableInterfaceType = context.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.IEquatable`1");
var interfaceWithGeneric = equatableInterfaceType.Construct(typeDefinition);
```

This should be enough to get you started. You can find more information about working with types in these articles: [Working with types in a Roslyn analyzer](https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/working-with-catch-blocks-in-your-roslyn-analyzer/), [Working With Catch Blocks in your Roslyn Analyzer](https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/working-with-catch-blocks-in-your-roslyn-analyzer/).